# Problema al subir imagenes desde php a la propiedades del plugin Estatik

Tags: php, wordpress, desarrollo

Estoy creando una integración para subir propiedades de un xml a wordpress concretamente al plugin Estatik, todo iba bien hasta que llegue a la parte de subir las imagenes, en Estatik hay un campo de galeria, la idea es subir las imagenes del xml ahi, al principio pense que solo tenia que subir las imagenes a los medios de wordpress y asociarla al post (propiedad) pero cuando se suben no se muestran en la propiedad, les dejo mi codigo:

```
            // Insertaremos el post en la base de datos
            $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
                'ID' => 5672800,
                'post_name' => $property_slug,
                'post_title' => $property_title,
                'post_content' => $property_desc,
                'post_type' => 'properties',
                'post_status' => 'private',
                'meta_input' => array(
                    'es_property_reference' => $property_ref,
                    // 'es_property_province' => $property_type,
                    // 'es_status' => $property_status,
                    // 'es_property_provincia' => $property_operation,
                    'es_property_price' => $property_price,
                    'es_property_country' => $property_country,
                    'es_property_city' => $property_city,
                    'es_property_province' => $property_province,
                    'es_property_address' => $property_location,
                    'es_postal_code' => $property_postcode,
                    'es_property_bedrooms' => $property_rooms,
                    'es_property_bathrooms' => $property_baths,
                    // 'es_property_province' => $property_pool,
                    'es_property_area' => $property_m2,
                    'galeria' => $gallery
                )
            ]);
            
            // Despues de subir la propiedad, subimos y relacionamos las imagenes
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    
            // Armamos el array de imagenes
            $images = $property->images->image;

            foreach($images as $img):           
                
                $url_image =  strval($img->url);
                $id_image = media_sideload_image($url_image, $inserted_property, null, 'src' );
    
            endforeach;
```

Comment: No he usado ese plugin, pero lo mas probable es que si hay una galeria, dicha galeria se llene con un array de ids, es decir, subes las imagenes y te retorna un id, esos ids los juntas en un array y luego lo adjuntas a la propiedad gallery, como dije, no he usado ese complemento, pero lo mas probable es que funcione asi ya que asi suelen funcionar otros complementos, revisa la documentación y si aun tienes dudas actualiza tu pregunta, tambien si lo solucionas, no estaria mal que publiques tu solucion.

Comment: Revisando los post meta de otras propiedades que ya estan subidas, no hay un meta key relacionado con galeria

Answer (score 0):

Probe esto y nada

```
// Despues de subir la propiedad, subimos y relacionamos las imagenes
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        // Armamos el array de imagenes
        $images = $property->images->image;
        $images_ids = array();

     // Si hay imagenes las recorremos una a una
        foreach ( $images as $img ) {

        // Subimos la imagen a nuestro servidor, le pasamos la url y retornamos el ID
            $image = media_sideload_image( strval($img->url), 0, null, 'id' );

        // Si no hay error llenamos nuestro array de ID's
            if ( !is_wp_error( $image ) ) :

                array_push( $images_ids, $image );

            endif;
            
            var_dump($images);
            die();
        }
        
        // Insertaremos el post en la base de datos
        $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
            'ID' => 5672800,
            'post_name' => $property_slug,
            'post_title' => $property_title,
            'post_content' => $property_desc,
            'post_type' => 'properties',
            'post_status' => 'private',
            'meta_input' => array(
                'es_property_reference' => $property_ref,
                // 'es_property_province' => $property_type,
                // 'es_status' => $property_status,
                // 'es_property_provincia' => $property_operation,
                'es_property_price' => $property_price,
                'es_property_country' => $property_country,
                'es_property_city' => $property_city,
                'es_property_province' => $property_province,
                'es_property_address' => $property_location,
                'es_postal_code' => $property_postcode,
                'es_property_bedrooms' => $property_rooms,
                'es_property_bathrooms' => $property_baths,
                // 'es_property_province' => $property_pool,
                'es_property_area' => $property_m2,
                'gallery' => $images_ids,
            )
        ]);
```